# get selected item ID from list view when click a button on the list view

Tags: wpf, listview

Below is `xaml` and `ListView`:

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvImages" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=resimGuncelle}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ID}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding RESIM_YOLU}" Width="120" Height="110" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" x:Name="txtx" x:Uid="dd" />
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource DaireButtonResimSil}" x:Name="btndil" Click="btndil_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I want to get Selected item ID , something like this:

```
 private void btndil_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedImageId = ((ResimGuncelleme)lvImages.SelectedItem).ID;

    }
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting this right, you have an `ItemDataModel` for your `ListView` items, and it has an `Id` property. Each time you click on a row predefined button you want to get that row item's `Id` property (without selecting the row, otherwise you could simply check the `ListView's` `SelectedItem` property).

Assuming your `ItemModel` looks something like this:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public BitmapSource ResimYolu { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

In your xaml you could pass the item where the button was clicked in the `Button`'s `Tag` using a `RelativeSource` binding:

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lvImages" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResimGuncelle}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Id}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Image">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding ResimYolu}" Width="120" Height="110" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" x:Name="txtx" x:Uid="dd" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Button">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="btndil" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"  Content="Button" Click="btndil_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And you can get that item's id from your button's click handler:

```
 private void btndil_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        var item=((sender as Button)?.Tag as ListViewItem)?.DataContext;
        var itemId = (item as ItemModel)?.Id;            
 }
```

Ps: this isn't a very clean way to do that!